# Debug Logs / LMA / and Async methods

Tags: managed-package, logging

Can anyone confirm that when logged into a subscriber org via the LMA that debug logs for your namespace are still obfuscated when running async methods (future, batch, etc).

1. If so, is there a work around that anyone has found? Curious if there is something specific to our package (listing has been around since 2009) or if it is widespread
2. If not, can someone with premier support submit a bug pretty please...

This has been happing for over a year now and I just had another customer with an issue during a future method calling our API and I was unable to get the debug logs.

Running the exact same code during the same LMA session with the @future removed and the logs were produced as expected. Problem was that the error only happened during @future context (which help me narrow my guesses down a bit) so the log was useless lol

With the @future annotation the logs just say a bunch of "Entering Managed Package" with the Details only having the namespace and nothing else....

**Workaround for batch**
If your execute method is global then you can re-create the query in the dev console and pass in the list of sObjects to the execute method and null for the query locator thus running synch. But that only helps if your class is global which you do not want to do just for this purpose as you can never change it....

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is LMA?

Comment: @DavidCheng - License Management App for ISV's